# solr server returned 405 status: method not allowed

Tags: java, solr

iam trying to index the document which is from url ,the solr throws the exception as below.Solr is 4.6 version and the sample code which is trying to index the document is :

```
UpdateRequest up = new UpdateRequest("/update/extract");
ModifiableSolrParams params = new ModifiableSolrParams();
params.set("stream.url", fileName);
params.set("stream.contentType", "text/html");

up.setParams(params);
solr.request(up);
solr.commit();


Exception occured :Server  returned non ok status:405, message:Method Not Allowed

please help.
```

Comment: Could you please add some more details about your index client? Which version of SOLR are you using? Could you post relevant lines of code of your solrj client?

Comment: @Andrea  i have added the details as per your request.

Answer (score 0):

Did you see the solrj example here?

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler#SolrJ

The code looks a little bit different.
In addition, having a look at sections before I see a "stream.file" parameter instead of your "stream.url"